# Matlab replacing 0 with empty cell in Cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a 10,000 x 65 Cell with 0's and 1's so for example if I type

> `C(1,1)` I get [0] returned or likewise C(3,4) a [1] is returned

I need a way to turn every 0 into a blank cell and every 1 into a char t

I've tried the following with little success

> `[rows, cols] = size(M);
>   for i = 1:rows
>       for j = 1:cols
>           if strcmp(M(i,j), 1) 
>           M(i,j) = 't';
>           end
>       end
>   end`

It returns the same thing, I'm guessing its not recognising the 1's as strings. Any idea sort of simply doing the conversion straight in Excel.
thanks

Comment: If you think the problem is that it's not recognizing them as string then did you try `if M(i,j)==1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the cell data-structure correctly.

First of all, if `M` really is a cell array, you will have to use `M{i,j}` to access the data. 
What `M(i,j)`does is just create a sub-cell-array, which contains `M{i,j}` as entry.

Also `strcmp` isn't used correctly, if your cell array contains strings you should use `strcmp(M{i,j}, '1')`. 
If your cell array on the other hand contains integers, you would have to use: `M{i,j}==1`.